# Buck converter: PWM modulator input waveform

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

I have a question about the pwm modulator in a classical buck converter in voltage mode control (VMC). For the circuit in question, I copied over the picture provided in the answer of another SE question (see here [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505298/pwm-modulator-in-voltage-mode-buck-converter))

[image: Voltage mode control]

What is the reason that the comparator is fed by a saw waveform in 99.9% (that´s my feeling at least) of all the circuits where it seems that any linear waveform is possible. From my understanding I would say that generating a triangular waveform is easier than a ramp (at least if done analog with an opamp) - so I guess there is a reason that "saw" is beneficial compared to "triangular"? On the other hand, the question I refer to also shows a variant with a triangular shape and calls that "dual edge" modulation. I did not see a drawback of that variant there...
But as I said, after googling quite a while, the "saw" variant seems to be the de facto standard. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

All that matters for the left side, is that it goes up and down in a mostly-linear fashion, so that the PWM(V(CMP)) *transfer function* is mostly linear.

For control purposes, we desire predictable loop gain, and the easiest way to ensure that is a triangular wave.  The rising and falling edges indeed don't matter, and a sawtooth can be considered a special case of a triangle wave, and both do as well here.  Indeed, you see real examples of both (e.g. [TL494](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf) triangle, [UC3842](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3842.pdf) sawtooth).

Sometimes even an RC time constant is used, where the exponential curve is simply truncated low enough that the slope hasn't decreased too far.  I've even built one of these from [vacuum tubes](https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/tmoranwms/Elec_Compound2.html#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20the%20complete%20schematic,%20with%20filtering%20and%20RC%20coupling%20to%20a%20transformer) a long time ago, where the high supply voltage and low signal voltage make a quite reasonable ramp waveform; no feedback correction was found necessary.

In SMPS, the loop doesn't need to be particularly linear, and the (incremental) gain can vary by a modest factor, so a somewhat gross ramp is tolerable; but mind that it introduces a level-dependent change in compensation, so makes things harder to test (you need to check compensation at multiple output or supply settings), and limits how close to optimal you can get (since the best case will always be over-compensated while the worst-case condition is merely marginally compensated).

Now, there may be additional reasons why a sawtooth is preferred.  Viewing the voltage-mode side in isolation, the above is true.  Viewing the circuit as a whole, we notice a flip-flop must be reset every cycle, otherwise the output simply latches on.  The phase relation is not shown, but presumably this coincides with the sawtooth falling edge.  And again we have real examples, such as the UC3842, which generates such an internal pulse while the oscillator is discharging.

Alternately, the flip-flop could be a type-D, with D tied to +1, the clock is any duty cycle, and R is used as shown (S unused).  But this takes up more transistors, and it's more convenient to just generate a "runt pulse", and furthermore to generate this from the falling edge of a waveform, so it works out conveniently to do it this way.

Interestingly, the circuit can also be simplified: simply add the two sides together, superimposed.  (Well, replace Vcs,max with V(CMP) probably.)  This changes operation slightly (it's not an identity transformation), but basic operation remains (the flip-flop is reset progressively along the cycle depending on levels), and as it turns out, dynamics are greatly improved: now the control level depends jointly on time *and* sensed inductor current -- a feed-forward effect that separates the L and C poles that the pure voltage-mode control otherwise has to be compensated well beneath.  This *current mode control* allows loop compensation closer to Fsw, above what would otherwise be the LC double-pole, greatly improving performance.